# Is there a way to read the datatable and examples of a scenario using eventPublisher in cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber

I have a requirement to parse the cucumber features for which I am using event publisher. However I am unable to read the data table of a step and also example attached to the scenario.

```
public class DryRunPlugin implements EventListener {
@Override
public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
    publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestCaseStarted.class, this::handleCaseStarted);
}

private void handleCaseStarted(TestCaseStarted event) {
 
    Iterator steps = event.getTestCase().getTestSteps().iterator();
    while(steps.hasNext())
    {
        Object stp = steps.next();
        if(stp instanceof PickleStepTestStep)
        {
            PickleStepTestStep p = (PickleStepTestStep) stp;
            String keyword = p.getStep().getKeyWord().toString();
            String stepText = p.getStep().getText();
            System.out.println(keyword + stepText);

            Object dataTable = p.getStep().getArgument();
            System.out.println(dataTable.getClass());
            if(dataTable !=null)
            {
                //GherkinVintageDataTableArgument arg = (GherkinVintageDataTableArgument)dataTable;
                //Object Rows = (dataTable.cells();
            }
            
        }

    }
}
```

}

When I am trying to use GherkinVintageDataTableArgument, it is giving me an error so not able to access the datatable to print. I am using cucumber version 5.5

**Error :**  io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.GherkinVintageDataTableArgument is not public in io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage. Cannot be accessed from outside the package

Comment: Putting the error in the question can help.

Comment: @onetwo12 I have added the error just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `Step.getArgument()` shows:

```
@API(status = API.Status.STABLE)
public interface Step {

    /**
     * Returns this Gherkin step argument. Can be either a data table or doc
     * string.
     *
     * @return a step argument, null if absent
     */
    StepArgument getArgument();
```

Then looking at `StepArgument` you'll see an empty interface with two sub interfaces, `DataTableArgument` and `DocStringArgument`.

```
@API(status = API.Status.STABLE)
public interface StepArgument {

}
```

And you'll want to use:

```
package io.cucumber.plugin.event;

import org.apiguardian.api.API;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Represents a Gherkin data table argument.
 */
@API(status = API.Status.STABLE)
public interface DataTableArgument extends StepArgument {

    List<List<String>> cells();

    int getLine();

}
```

You may also have seen several concrete implementations of the interface such as `GherkinVintageDataTableArgument` but you can't access these because they are [package private](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

This is intentional.

A plugin should only have to use classes and interfaces from the `cucumber-plugin` module. This ensures you don't depend on internal implementation details of Cucumber and your plugin is likely to work when upgrading. So try using the `io.cucumber.plugin.event.DataTableArgument` instead.

> I have a requirement to parse the cucumber features for which I am using event publisher.

Depending on what you are actually trying to achive the fidelity provided by Cucumber may not be enough. Consider using a gherkin parser on the source provided by the `TestSourceRead` event.

Comment: are you aware of any article which details the parsing of gherkin files?

Comment: M.P. Korstanje, I have got one more workaround by using a class "DataTableArgument". I used DataTableArgument dtr = (DataTableArgument) dataTable;